# How to fill dropdowlist in ASP.NET with two range of the year

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

How I have single dropdownlist ASP.NET, how to fill programmatically with c# or VB.NET with two range of year? so as example the output is '2013-2014' then '2014-2015' etc.

Hope Your answer
Thank You very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
var startYear = 2013;
var rangeCount = 10;
var ranges = Enumerable.Range( 2013, rangeCount ).Select( y => y + "-" + ( y + 1 ) );

yourDropDownList.DataSource = ranges;
yourDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @st4hoo, but I'm using VB.Net Language. an error detected and say "ranges is not declared", can you help me?

"Dim startYear = 2013
        Dim rangeCount = 10
        Dim ranges = Enumerable.Range(2013, rangeCount).Select(() => {  }, (y + ("-" + (y + 1))))
        cmb_tahun_masuk.DataSource = ranges
        cmb_tahun_masuk.DataBind()"

Comment: `Dim ranges = Enumerable.Range(2013, rangeCount).Select(Function(y)  y & "-" & (y+1))`

Comment: The enumeration.Range is a nice bit of code. I wanted you to know that this example provided me with excellent value.